# criterion for geometrically integral scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I want to prove the remark 3.2.9 of the book Algebraic Geometry of Arithmetic Curves (of Quing Liu) that is: let $X$ be an integral scheme with function field $K(X)$, if $K(X)\otimes_k \overline{k}$ is integral then $X$ is geometrically integral (that is $X_\overline{k}$ is an integral sheme). The proof is going so: for all open $U\subseteq X$, one has $\mathcal{O}(U_\overline{k})\simeq\mathcal{O}(U)\otimes_k \overline{k}\subseteq K(X)\otimes_k \overline{k}$. So $\mathcal{O}(U_\overline{k})$ is integral, forall $U$ and so $X_\overline{k}$ is integral.

My problem is the last implication: I know that a scheme $Y$ is integral if for **all** open $V\subseteq Y$, $\mathcal{O}(V)$ is integral. But in the proof the open $U_\overline{k}$ are not all the open (I guess). So how to conclude.

Maybe the $U_\overline{k}$ are all the open?

Maybe there is a criterion for integral scheme that would be: $X$ is integral if $X$ is cover by $U_i$ such that for all $i$, $\mathcal{O}(U_i)$ is integral?

Comment: The last statement is correct.

Comment: (1) No, not all open subsets of $X_{\bar{k}}$ are defined over $k$. (2) No it is not enough that $X$ is covered by integral open subsets: consider the disjoint union of two integral open subsets.  But it becomes sufficient if we ask $X$ be connected: if there are more than 1 components, then at least two of them intersect and there is no integral open subset containing any intersection point. Finally, for the original question: as $O(X_{\bar{k}})$ is integral, $X_{\bar{k}}$ is connected. By (2) and the results you cite, this implies that $X_{\bar{k}}$ is integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is true: if $X$ is an irreducible scheme such that there exists an open cover by affine integral schemes, then $X$ is integral. In your case, you can get an open cover with affin open sets of the form $U_{\bar{k}}$.

Comment: You need to add some irreducibility assumptions.

Comment: Ok I see. But I don't see why my scheme $X_\overline{k}$  is irreducible?